# QObject memory management and smart pointers

Tags: c++, qt

What are the main differences between the use of QObject memory management and smart pointers? When is it better to use this or that mechanism?

Comment: You don't really have a choice. With smart pointers you have to get the order of destruction right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you probably know, at destruction `QObject` will destroy all their children, this is what we call "QObject memory management". Children are typically added to a `QObject *parent` from their constructor with `new QObject(parent);`.

*Smart pointers* on the other hand, is more a category than a specific type,
 including shared pointers, auto pointers, etc. which have an implementation in both the STL *and* Qt in C++ (only to name those two).

So even though they are not directly comparable, I would sum it that way:

### Use QObject memory management when ...

1. Your object is a QWidget, of course, or GUI related
2. You don't need/want to store the pointer

   ```
   MyObject *object = new MyObject(this);
   object->setSomething();
   // And you don't ever need to access it later
   ```
3. Your object only tied to its parent lifespan. In that case, you won't need to create an additional smart pointer over it, and you will be able to store it as a simple `QObject*`
4. You need the `QObject` hierarchy and/or find features, which let you do stuff like below. See [QObject documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) for more details.

   ```
   // Get children
   auto childrenList = this->children();
   // Find a specific child
   MyObject* child = this->findChild<MyObject*>("specific name");
   ```

If you fall in one of these cases and your object is shared, you might want to use `QObjectPointer` type too, which will be automatically reset whenever the pointed `QObject` is destroyed.

### Use smart pointers when ...

1. Your object is *not* a `QObject` based type, of course
2. Your object is local (deleted at the end of the scope), in which case you need a `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr`. QObject parenting would be most likely overkill here, and dangerous.
3. Your object is shared, and thus requires a `QSharedPointer` or `std::shared_pointer`/`std::weak_ptr`. Again, QObject parenting could delete your `QObject` at any time, which is not what you want when using shared pointers.

### None of the above?

Then it is up to you, they serve different purposes.

- In Qt GUI related code, I tend to prefer `QObject` parenting: simple, and will nicely integrate with Qt code. Careful as the call stack will be a little less clear to understand if you are debugging though.
- Outside of the UI, or to interface with non-UI related code, I prefer pure C++: The less external dependencies, the better!

Comment: auto_ptr is deprecated in C++11 (D.10, page 1228), it will also be deleted in a future version of C++ so It should not be used at all.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right!

Comment: To make sure I got it right: `auto p = std::make_unique<QPushButton>(this)` is a mix of two ways of memory management and will cause trouble?

Comment: @Petross404 That's right, the memory management is already taken care of by your button's parent (`this` in your case), and the unique_ptr doesn't add anything if you just want your button to be destroyed when your widget/window/parent gets destroyed. You don't want Qt to delete it while you have a unique_ptr pointing to it as well :).

Comment: So that's why my valgrind analysis insists about errors. Forgive me one last question: If initialization with parent serves the purpose of placing the child widget (visually) on top of parent and memory management as well, then what is the purpose of c++ smart pointers for Qt widgets?

Comment: @Petross404 In my humble opinion, there is no point in using both. C++ smart pointers are very useful when you want to manage anything allocated on the heap, that is not already "memory-managed". For example if you were to create a std::vector on the heap, or QVector the same. There are tons of situation where you want to use them, just not this one!